# PDF generation in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, pdf, reporting-services

We currently send an email notification in plain text or html format.  Our environment is C#/.NET/SQL Server.

I'd like to know if anyone recommends a particular solution.  I see two ways of doing this:

- dynamically convert current email to pdf using a third party library and sending the pdf as an attachment

or

- use SSRS to allow users to export pdf report (could eventually have SSRS push reports)

I'm open to third party libraries (especially if they are open source and free).  It seems that SSRS is the simplest and easiest way to go. Anyone have any tips?

Comment: All email should be in plain text.  HTML is bad and PDF is worse.  Could you explain to SO *why* you are torturing your people in this way?

Comment: It might be useful to add additional information which can't be easily represented in a text email in PDF, but there is no point in converting an existing email to PDF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) to convert your html pages to pdf. Here's an example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string html = 
@"<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=utf-8"" />
</head>
<body>
  <p style=""color: red;"">Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>";

        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        using (Stream output = new FileStream("out.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        using (StringReader htmlReader = new StringReader(html))
        using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(htmlReader))
        {
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
            HtmlParser.Parse(document, reader);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: the base string is just a div section <div>stuff</div>.

the file gets created, but cannot be opened.

does the code you posted work or was it just mockup?

Answer (score 0):

[iText-Sharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/)
Works very much like the java version, and has both great documentation and multiple books available.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need simple html -> pdf conversion, look at [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org). It's free, opensource, command line utility based on webkit.

If you want something more complex like prepare multiple templates or store history of pdf outputs. Look at reporting server [jsreport](http://jsreport.net)